# Javascript regexp for query conversion

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to convert a string into an expression using regexp in javascript. Lets say we have a string.

`let element = "id == 123 and status IN ('Active','null')"`.

I need to find this string has null value and if its present convert to the below expression

`id == 123 and status IN ('Active') or status is null`.

I tried using this function but could not append **status** before **is null** as I want it to append dynamically

```
expressionFunc = (element) => {
  if(element.includes('null')) return `${element1.replace(new RegExp(",?'null',?"),'')} or is null`
};
```

Comment: You may use `replace(/,?'null'(?:,|(\)))?/g, '$1 or status is null')`

Comment: The __status__ should not be added as such it has to find from the query

Comment: Then it is not clear. Try `replace(/,'(\w+)'\)/, ') or status is null')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example string, you could capture the value for status in a group, the part until 'null' in a group and the part after 'null' in a group and use those groups in the replacement.

```
(\S+)(\s+IN\s+\(.*?),?\s*'null'(.*?\))
```

The pattern in parts:

- `(\S+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ non whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `\s+IN\s+\(.*?` Match  `IN (` followed by as least as possible chars
- `),?` Close group 2 and match optional comma
- `\s*'null'` Match `'null'` preceded by optional whitespace chars
- `(.*?\))` Capture **group 3** Match as least as possible till `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xTw0Lw/1)

And replace with

```
$1$2$3 or $1 is null
```

```js
const expressionFunc = e =>
  e.replace(
    /(\S+)(\s+IN\s+\(.*?),?'null'(.*?\))/g,
    `$1$2$3 or $1 is null`
  );
const element = `id == 123 and status IN ('Active','null')`;
console.log(expressionFunc(element));
```

Comment: That's cool. But it fails for this status IN ('null','Active') adding a comma before Active

Comment: @ReNinja You might use an alternation to match the comma on either side, but not on both `(\S+)(\s+IN\s+\(.*?)(?:'null',?\s*|,?\s*'null')(.*?\))` https://regex101.com/r/GbEpOe/1

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have any extra condition then the below code will work as expected.

```js
let element = "id == 123 and status IN ('Active','null')";
if(element.includes('null')) {
  let ret = element.replace('\,\'null\'', "") + " or status is null";
  console.log(ret);
}
```